# Is it possible to create a Review App dynamically?

Tags: heroku, angular-cli

On Heroku pipelines, there's a option to create the pipeline automatically or when the PR is created (clicking on the button). But looks like that there's no option to trigger that by the terminal, after running the tests or doing some modification.

The is a monorepo of multiple projects based on a env variable ([like this example](https://github.com/intellix/angular-cli-library)).

Currently to build a specific application we have to hardcode the `app.json`, but it's not possible to add a second pipeline with differents variables, or even dynamically build (based on a tag or whatever) without hardcoding

Comment: Seems like most of platforms I've looked at far (Heroku, Netlify to name a couple) don't have good stories for handling a monorepo of static sites. Have you found anything else on your travels?

Comment: @WildService yeah, I didn't found anything related how to do that. I've created a bot to reproduce the PR in a forked repo (which I configure the others repos), was the only solution that i've found to automate it